# GIF generating website that generates a true-transparent background

Tags: gif

Many sites offer gif generation services with the option to create a transparent background behind a gif, however, when placed on a dark background, you can see edges around the animated gif. Ajax-loader.com and chimply.com (as well as many others) do not work as well as I had anticipated.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a place where I can find a true-transparent background loading gif?

Note: I cannot rely on a different color background, the site uses a preloader already and I would much prefer not to have two.

Comment: Hey JCG, welcome to GD! Finding places that can generate a loading GIF isn't really in the scope of this site, but perhaps that duplicate question will help you explain why that's happening and how to fix it.

Comment: This is a shopping question, which for the most part, isn't allowed here. However, the problem is not with these sites, it's the gif file format. Gifs can only have 255 colors and one transparent color. Meaning if there's any full transparency, there can only be full transparency, then everything else is an opaque color. This messes with anti aliasing a bit. Edges that in a png would be 10% transparent, then a pixel over 60% transparent, and so on, until it reaches the full transparent background, are rendered as solid opaque pixels in gifs.

Comment: Sorry I haven't gotten back to this for a few days. My apologies that this is slightly out of scope for this site. Thanks for the duplicate, it was helpful, but I found a workaround that most definitely is not in the scope of this site.